# Isolate parent makefile environment from included makefile in gnumake

Tags: makefile, gnu, gnu-make

Lets say I have a makefile a.mk which has a variable named FILES used. a.mk includes b.mk which also does something using FILES as a variable name. Now when the execution comes back to a.mk, the FILES variable is modified which I don't want. How can I achieve this? I don't have the option of modifying b.mk. Basically I want the environment for a.mk and b.mk to be isolated from each other.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your only choices are to not include `b.mk` and use it as a sub-make instead (if that works) or to save and reset the variable around the `b.mk` inclusion.